# How to plot two different timeseries datasets with ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, next.js, chart.js, visualization

I'm trying to plot two different timeseries datasets (on the same chart) with ChartJS- first the price of a stock for the past 6 months, and then the forecast of that same stock for the following month.

I've got both the forecasts saved in different tables in Postgres, however I don't know how to set up the chart such that I get both, the historical price + the forecast.

This is how it's currently set up:

```
myChart = new Chart(canvasRef.current, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
          datasets: [
            {
            label: 'My Chart',
            data: data.map((d) => d.close),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            tension: 0.4
          },
          {
            label: '30-day forecast',
            data: data_pred.map((d) => d.mean),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            tension: 0.4
          }
        ]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            x: [{
              type: 'timeseries'
            }]
          }
        }
      })
```

As you can see, I am currently plotting `data_pred`, which is the forecast. And while this plots fine, it messes up my plot for the historical price line.

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could tell me how I could add the dates for both the timeseries on my X-axis. In my database, the dates are saved as datetime (ISO) objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add objects as `data` in a dataset (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object), and remove the `labels` option:

```
const cfg = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [{x: epoch, y: 20}, {x: epoch, y: 10}]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I tried this but it's still not working. I have put both the forecast data and the historical data in the same table and have different symbols for each so I can query them separately. 

This way I have all my dates in order in one table. 

However, even then it's not working. Do I have to use a date adapter?

Comment: Yes, you must, using timeseries scales